# Problem accessing linked list in C with a printf in a specific function (accessing memory problems)

Tags: c, list, memory

When I try to compile the code down below the executable does not open. 
I also tried debugging and I got this error in the printf of viewNode line: 
Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression (l)->info
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot access memory at address 0xeb

Now, I understand that I'm trying to access memory location that I shouldn't, but where's the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct char_node *char_list;

struct char_node{
    char info;
    char_list next;
}char_node;

char_list makesNode(void);
char_list makesValueNode(char value);
char_list makesList(char_list l, char nome[]);
void viewNode(char_list l);
void viewList(char_list l);

int main(){
    char_list nuovo;
    char nome[] = "Ugo";
    makesList(nuovo, nome);
    if(nuovo != NULL)
        viewList(nuovo);

    return 0;
}

char_list makesNode(void){
    return (char_list)malloc(sizeof(struct char_node));
}

char_list makesValueNode(char value){
    char_list li = NULL;
    li = makesNode();
    li -> info = value;
    li -> next = NULL;
    return li;
}

char_list makesList(char_list nuovo, char nome[]){
    char_list head = NULL;
    int l = strlen(nome);
    l = l - 1;
    while(l >= 0 ){
        nuovo = makesValueNode(nome[l]);
            if(nuovo != NULL){
                nuovo -> next = head;
                head = nuovo;
                l = l - 1;
            }
    }
    return nuovo;
}

void viewNode(char_list l){
    printf("%c", l->info);
}

void viewList(char_list l){
    while(l != NULL){
        viewNode(l);
        l = l -> next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of typedefing pointers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeList` returns the `char_list` pointer, but you're not assigning it to your variable.

Also, `makesList` never uses the `nuovo` parameter, there's no need for it.

So it should be:

```
int main(){
    char nome[] = "Ugo";
    char_list nuovo = makesList(nome);
    if(nuovo != NULL)
        viewList(nuovo);
    return 0;
}

char_list makesList(char nome[]){
    char_list nuovo;
    char_list head = NULL;
    int l = strlen(nome);
    l = l - 1;
    while(l >= 0 ){
        nuovo = makesValueNode(nome[l]);
        if(nuovo != NULL){
            nuovo -> next = head;
            head = nuovo;
            l = l - 1;
        }
    }
    return nuovo;
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/5Uox0b)

Comment: Thank you! This is obviously right, but the main problem isn't solved...

Comment: You have a tiny typo on line 3 of your example (stray semicolon)

Comment: @ClothingDiares, what do you mean "the main problem isn't solved"?  You're not storing the shiny new pointer, so you're accessing garbage through a random old one.  Fix that, fix the problem, no?

Comment: @ClothingDiares This is essentially the same as the answer you accepted, except he didn't remove the unused argument from `makesList`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you're not storing your newly created list as you think you are, so when you come to print it, you're printing garbage.

```c
int main(){
    char_list nuovo;       // <--- uninitialised pointer
    char nome[] = "Ugo";
    makesList(nuovo, nome);    // <--- not storing return value
    if(nuovo != NULL)
        viewList(nuovo);    // <--- printing some random memory, not your new list

    return 0;
}
```

If you change to:

```c
    char_list nuovo = NULL;
    ...
    nuovo = makesList(nuovo, nome);
```

You should find it works as you expect, but it's worth thinking a little about whether you really want it to work this way.

It looks like you might have been hoping that `nuovo` was magically updated by the function, but you'll need to pass a pointer to it for that (...and it's a different discussion!).

Finally, as @Barmar pointed out, `typedef`'ing pointers is a bad habit, and makes it all the more easy to leave them uninitialised as you have, simply because they don't *look* like pointers.